# How to use Real(); Complex(); functions to define a complex number in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I am from the simple numbers world of audio and i am finding complex number errors in Matlab coder compilation:

*The left-hand side has been constrained to be non-complex, but the right-hand side is complex. To correct this problem, make the right-hand side real using the function REAL, or change the initial assignment to the left-hand side variable to be a complex value using the COMPLEX function.*

How do i use real function in this scenario?

```
tfr= zeros (N,tcol) ;  
for icol=1:tcol,
tfr(1,icol)= sum(g2 .* x(ti-points,1) .* conj(x(ti-points,xcol))); % error here
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, working example

Comment: Okay, i summarized it so that there is only one line with a complex number error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> change the initial assignment to the left-hand side variable to be a complex value using the COMPLEX function.

Thus is exactly what you have to do.

```
tfr= complex(zeros (N,tcol) ) ;
```

You must tell the coder to allocate a variable with sufficient space for a complex variable.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use Real() function on the third line, to see if the resulting matlab compiled code is simpler? perhaps one method generates less concise code than the other?

Comment: You would have to put it around the sum, but that would simply ignore the imaginary part. From your code I assumed that you are dealing with imaginary values.

Answer (score 0):

This has taken care of it for the moment:

changing initial array statement:

```
carr= zeros (N,tcol) ;  
tfr = complex(carr,0);
```

there are probably better answers.